# Handle "std::bad_alloc: out_of_memory: CUDA error" at Dask-cudf

Tags: python-3.x, dask, rapids

I have a pc with a Nvida 3090 and 32GB ram.

I am loading a 9GB csv dataset, with millions of rows and 5 columns.

Anytime I run `compute()` it doesn't work and throws `std::bad_alloc: out_of_memory: CUDA error`.

How can I handle this data in my pc? To perform all the statistical operations, plots, ML, etc ...

Comment: Does this happen during the load/read time (unlikely) or after some processing? If the latter, it would help to know which operations you are performing.

Comment: note that `compute()` loads the result fully into memory. So the out of memory issue could occur at a memory bottleneck during the workflow or just in computing the final result. 32GB isn't a ton of room for a 9GB dataset in a ML pipeline - all you need is a dimensionality expansion or a couple copies and you're done, so the diagnosis is very dependent on your chunking scheme and your workflow. not much else we can do without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using a single GPU to process this and trying to use dask_cudf to allow you run larger than GPU manipulations.  As Michael said, compute() returns a cudf resultant dataframe that must fit on the GPU as well as the dask_cudf processing space.  You can use .persist().  Coiled has a great blog on this: https://coiled.io/blog/dask-persist-dataframe/

Another option is to use dask-sql with RAPIDS and convert your data from csv to parquet.  That can allow you to quickly and easily do chunked out of core processing of your data.